# How to attach mesh to particle system?

Tags: mesh, hair

So I have a hair particle system animated with wind, and I want the hairband to move with it. Is it possible to do this without converting the hair to mesh? I've tried that but my computer cannot handle that much vertex while simulating with the cloth animation. The hair animation goes smoothly, so I'd prefer that if it's possible.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the hair and the hairband and the modifiers? Has the hairband a cloth simulation? If you're looking for an option to attach a hair tie/hairband or a bow on a braid then the *Particle Instance* modifier can help you.